# Error: Finish can only be called once

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with Gradle building. When I build my project, it displays the error:

> Finish can only be called once in android studio

Anyone have idea about this error?

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart android studio, and after that clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but what do you mean invalidate cache? I did these all steps yet but it's still not running.

Comment: To Invalidate cache and restart. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842737/errortrouble-processing-java-lang-autocloseable-class/43843010#43843010)

Answer (score 35):

in android studios go to ....
file > invalidate caches and restart ....
click invalidate and restart button in confirmation dialog..

might take few time to build Gradle..

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution and IMO should be marked as the accepted answer. It worked for me and has the bonus of not going into the file system and wiping out system folders ;)

Answer (score 14):

I was able to resolve this issue by stopping the currently running gradle daemon so from command line:

`./gradlew --stop`

Or if you're using android studio: Restart android studio.

I've cleared the cache in advance but it didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Close Android Sudio, on your Home directory (on windows : C:\Users\YourUserName) enter .gradle directory and erase caches directory, then restart Android Studio and the error should be solved.

[image]

on windows : C:\Users\YourUserName) enter .gradle directory and erase caches directory

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: What is the fix for Mac?

Comment: @bwicks path for mac is `~/.gradle/caches`

Comment: Still in 2017 and still seeing this error code. The Android Studio IDE itself should take care of stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

if you run Android Studio as root, then run gradle commands as root too, try `sudo ./gradlew assembleDebug` or `sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 1):

There are many sophisticated answers. But for me none of this helped, only reboot.

Answer (score 1):

A simple restart of android studio works.

Answer (score 0):

People, if you are using Android Studio in mac, by default you will be getting a BUILD file added in your project.Not sure whether it is bug or might be added default to all Android Studio Projects. Make sure to delete 
BUILD file and then restart Android Studio. If you see the same error "Error: Finish can only be called once" again then restart your computer.As i faced this issue many times, this solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

error "Finish: only can be called once"

Gradle cache problem: The default amount of cache path in:

on windows: C: \ Users \ YourUserName)

1, exit the studio

2, enter the cache path, find C: \ Users \ Administrator . Gradle

3, delete the caches folder or delete. gradle folder

4, restart studio to rebuild;

Answer (score -3):

recreate andoid studio configuration.

1. close problem project.
2. remove .iml files and .gradle .idea directories.
3. open project.