# Error: trouble processing "java/lang/AutoCloseable.class"

Tags: android, android-studio, autocloseable

When I compile my project, I am getting this error:

> trouble processing `java/lang/AutoCloseable.class`

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: Have you tried _Invalid Cache and Restart_ ? Ek var try kari jo @Khyati Chitroda

Comment: yes, but still getting same.

Comment: Any other error details? Because as i know it is related with Java 7

Comment: Error:trouble processing "java/lang/AutoCloseable.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken

Comment: Have you updated JDK version ? After updating use _Invalid Cache and Restart_

Answer (score 2):

Try doing Invalidate cache and restart. This should fix if it is only a build issue.

[image]

Comment: I have tried same as you explain but getting same error.

Comment: try building some other project and see if that if building.

Comment: Other project builds properly, I am getting error in only one project, 
Sorry Shashank for late reply.

Comment: then it doesn't look like a jdk error.. It has to be some library dependency in your project